# Ising model, phase transition

Tags: statistical-physics, ising-model

What is the temperature for the phase transition  in the triangular-lattice Ising model? and in the hexagonal-lattice Ising model?

Answer (score 8):

I presume this is for a ferromagnetic interaction with all bonds of strength $J$.

The critical temperatures can be found using Kramers-Wannier duality and a star-triangle transformation.  According to [these notes](http://www.brandonrayhaun.com/2016/01/09/dualities-in-two-dimensional-ising-models/) they are $4J/\log(3)$ for the triangular and $2J/\log(2+\sqrt{3})$ for the hexagonal lattice.